# Crash: Search not working on tvOS 16 and xcode14

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I have created a SearchContainer as:

```
 func createSearch(storyboard: UIStoryboard?) -> UIViewController {
        guard let movieListController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieListViewController") as? MovieListViewController else {

            fatalError("Unable to instantiate a NewsController")
        }
        
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: movieListController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = movieListController
        
        let searchContainer = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
        searchContainer.title = "Search"
        return searchContainer
    }
```

But it's crashing while scrolling, may be I'm not doing anything for focus engine as a newbie on tvOS.

Crash stack as below:

```html
<div style="white-space:pre">
2022-10-15 20:30:41.175226+0530 MovieDBTV[6291:2986887] *** Assertion failure in -[UIFocusSystem _focusEnvironmentWillDisappear:], UIFocusSystem.m:741
2022-10-15 20:30:41.223217+0530 MovieDBTV[6291:2986887] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The newly focused item or one of its parent environments is getting removed from the hierarchy in response of that item becoming focused. This is a client bug that leaves the focus system in an undefined state. Focused item: <MovieDBTV.MovieCell: 0x7fc788065a40; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (1053 80; 300 550); opaque = NO; focused = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002b95420>>; environment being removed: <MovieDBTV.MovieCell: 0x7fc788065a40; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (1053 80; 300 550); opaque = NO; focused = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002b95420>>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff8007a82a1 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007ff80004dbb4 objc_exception_throw + 48
2 Foundation 0x00007ff8015b2ef0 $s10Foundation32FormatStyleCapitalizationContextV10CodingKeys33_7052156219470F75D5F20BC0C8A29F87LLOwup + 521520
3 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b90a142 -[UIFocusSystem _focusEnvironmentWillDisappear:] + 1185
4 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b5def1d -[UICollectionView _reuseCell:notifyDidEndDisplaying:] + 1079
5 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b600d3f -[UICollectionView _reusePreviouslyFocusedManagedSubviewIfNeeded:] + 140
6 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b5f883e -[UICollectionView _setFocusedItemState:] + 244
7 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b5bcfdb -[UICollectionView reloadData] + 1971
8 MovieDBTV 0x000000010fbf9474 $s9MovieDBTV0A18ListViewControllerC6moviesSayAA0A0VGvW + 180
9 MovieDBTV 0x000000010fbf9565 $s9MovieDBTV0A18ListViewControllerC6moviesSayAA0A0VGvs + 117
10 MovieDBTV 0x000000010fbfb67d $s9MovieDBTV0A18ListViewControllerC19updateSearchResults3forySo08UISearchE0C_tF + 125
11 MovieDBTV 0x000000010fbfc2b5 $s9MovieDBTV0A18ListViewControllerC19updateSearchResults3forySo08UISearchE0C_tFTo + 53
12 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf8f67c __65-[UISearchController _performAutomaticPresentationFromTextField:]_block_invoke + 1110
13 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf8f1f4 -[UISearchController _performAutomaticPresentationFromTextField:] + 368
14 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf8e5ee -[UISearchController _performDidBeginEditingForSearchBar:] + 92
15 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf8e749 -[UISearchController _searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:] + 106
16 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b48394b -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _searchFieldBeginEditing] + 160
17 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf0c09d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 95
18 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b7f97c4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 110
19 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b7f9bb5 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 336
20 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c255ba8 -[UITextField _attachFieldEditor] + 486
21 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c24882e -[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 167
22 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b48944f -[UISearchTextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 87
23 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3cb4a -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 777
24 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c44e2f4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 121
25 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c247329 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 180
26 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bb58bcf -[UISystemInputViewController _resetDelegate] + 178
27 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bb58e79 -[UISystemInputViewController setupKeyboard] + 217
28 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bb59118 -[UISystemInputViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 78
29 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c4641d2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1358
30 QuartzCore 0x00007ff806578130 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 526
31 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c44fdf2 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1447
32 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b87e61e __97-[_UISearchControllerATVSearchBarAnimatorLegacy willFocusOffscreenViewForController:withHeading:]_block_invoke + 429
33 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c45865c +[UIView _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:optionsanimations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 588
34 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83c458a23 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] + 30
35 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b87e358 -[_UISearchControllerATVSearchBarAnimatorLegacy willFocusOffscreenViewForController:withHeading:] + 3283
36 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf8cdd4 -[UISearchController _willUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:] + 836
37 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b90d395 __85-[UIFocusSystem _sendWillUpdateFocusNotificationsInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:]_block_invoke + 67
38 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b8aeb78 _UIFocusEnvironmentEnumerateAncestorEnvironments + 131
39 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b90d9c2 -[UIFocusSystem _sendNotificationsForFocusUpdateInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:usingBlock:] + 418
40 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b90d005 -[UIFocusSystem _sendWillUpdateFocusNotificationsInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:] + 178
41 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b90c6e8 -[UIFocusSystem _updateFocusWithContext:report:] + 328
42 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b90dc2b -[UIFocusSystem _updateFocusImmediatelyWithContext:] + 103
43 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b911515 -[_UIFocusMovementPerformer performFocusMovement:] + 484
44 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf63b40 -[UIWindow _focusEventRecognizer:didRecognizeFocusMovementRequest:] + 147
45 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b8dbef6 -[_UIFocusEventRecognizer _didRecognizeFocusMovementRequest:] + 79
46 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b8dc209 -[_UIFocusEventRecognizer _moveInDirection:groupFilter:withSearchInfo:] + 321
47 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b8dc5df -[_UIFocusEventRecognizer _handleArrowButtonGesture:] + 639
48 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b9e55ce -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 72
49 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b9ee7b8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 100
50 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b9eb671 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 294
51 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b9eaa36 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureForActiveEvents] + 633
52 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b9daa29 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 3840
53 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b9d96d2 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent] + 848
54 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf4ef9e -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3708
55 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf24adb -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 907
56 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf1c80c -[UIApplication _sendButtonEventWithPressInfo:] + 190
57 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf27567 -[UIApplication _handleKeyboardPressEvent:] + 2660
58 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf0fdc0 -[UIApplication pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 392
59 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
60 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
61 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
62 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
63 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
64 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b69b984 -[UITabBarController pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 115
65 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
66 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
67 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
68 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
69 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
70 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
71 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
72 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
73 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
74 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
75 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
76 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b5f6678 __43-[UICollectionView pressesBegan:withEvent:]_block_invoke.2363 + 50
77 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b5f64b9 -[UICollectionView _handlePresses:selectHandler:keyHandler:defaultHandler:] + 779
78 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83b5f65ee -[UICollectionView pressesBegan:withEvent:] + 189
79 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3c4e3 forwardTouchMethod + 312
80 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf4de36 -[UIWindow _sendButtonsForEvent:] + 393
81 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf4efba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3736
82 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf24adb -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 907
83 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf260d7 -[UIApplication _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 572
84 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
85 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
86 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
87 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
88 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
89 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
90 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
91 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
92 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
93 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
94 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
95 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
96 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
97 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
98 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
99 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
100 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
101 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
102 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf3ff9f -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
103 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf26183 -[UIApplication handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
104 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf25e7a -[UIApplication _handleKeyHIDEvent:usingSyntheticEvent:] + 893
105 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bfbc74d __processEventQueue + 8762
106 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bfb4c5a __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 241
107 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800709205 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
108 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800709144 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
109 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800708954 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
110 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff8007031c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 927
111 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800702a6d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
112 GraphicsServices 0x00007ff8044752db GSEventRunModal + 139
113 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf05cc6 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
114 UIKitCore 0x00007ff83bf0ab52 UIApplicationMain + 123
115 MovieDBTV 0x000000010fbf7a5f main + 63
116 dyld 0x000000010fec925d start_sim + 10
117 ??? 0x000000011713752e 0x0 + 4682118446
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.7 - Device: Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (2nd generation) (0F1E24BE-2FE5-4964-BB56-3299BA71DD82) - Runtime: tvOS 16.0 (20J373) - DeviceType: Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (2nd generation)
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The newly focused item or one of its parent environments is getting removed from the hierarchy in response of that item becoming focused. This is a client bug that leaves the focus system in an undefined state. Focused item: <MovieDBTV.MovieCell: 0x7fc788065a40; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (1053 80; 300 550); opaque = NO; focused = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002b95420>>; environment being removed: <MovieDBTV.MovieCell: 0x7fc788065a40; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (1053 80; 300 550); opaque = NO; focused = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002b95420>>.</div>
```

Sample App Code: https://github.com/alfianlosari/MovieDBtvOS